# How can I change the connection speed of a port programmatically?

Tags: scripting, switch-statement, snmp

I need to change the connection speed of a port on a switch via program or script. Possible choices are 100M Full Duplex, 10M Full and 10M Half Duplex.

The server runs a Linux Debian. The switches are "talked to" via SNMP.

How can I do it? Best would be Perl and/or PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would also matter if the switch is part of your computer or not. Most switches I have seen are boxes that are part of your network. They have various methods of talking to them. If its a better one you can make an ssh connection and issue some commands to change the configuration. Such as switch should be fairly easy to automate as a script.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that it's a lower level task. Try to google "linux traffic shaper".